# A new motherboard or a new ATI graphics chip?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, laptop-repair

I have a Dell Studio 1558 laptop which was purchased in July 2010 and I am now facing a problem with it. The laptop switches off automatically after working for around 15 minutes.
When I gave it to the Dell authorized service center, they said, I need to replace the mother board.

I then gave it to an another service center and they said that the in-built ATI Radeon 5470 chip is faulty, and it needs to be replaced.

Could replacing the ATI work or should I be looking at a new board?

Comment: Have you tried opening it up and cleaning the heat pipes/fans of dust? You could also try a laptop cooling mat (the symptoms would match a heat issue too).

Comment: I don't think you'll find anyone who would even attempt to swap out the 5470 chip from the motherboard. If the 5470 is faulty, you need a new motherboard.

Comment: I edited your question as it was off topic. I'm hoping it's on topic now and that I didn't change the question too much!

Comment: The advice is exactly the same.  In order to replace the ATI chip they have to replace the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

For almost all laptops, the graphics card is part of the motherboard.  It's physically soldered in place, and they cannot be removed separately.

Your laptop is among these.  If either the motherboard or graphics card go bad, the entire motherboard -- which includes the graphics card -- must be replaced.

Comment: But the service technicians outside of Dell says that, it can be replaced, and they have done it many times.
Not just that, I don't think that the ATI chip is soldered there. An Intel in-built graphics chip is soldered. How can I ensure that, the ATI chip is not soldered and it can be replaced. My ATI chip's code is 1YNXH

Comment: This is the motherboard for your laptop; it's discrete graphics (it's not the same piece of silicon as the CPU), but it is soldered in place.

http://www.parts-people.com/index.php?action=item&id=10269&gclid=ck71s6fk_bucfuhv4aodnx0aya

Answer (score 0):

Although I would hope that the tech support that you inqured with were reputable enough to tell you the truth, you should rule out heat buildup first. If you can hear the fan spinning and feel hot air coming from the vent, spend a few dollars on a can of air and an afternoon with a screwdriver could fix everything. Cheap fix or cheap piece of mind of the board being the issue.

If the clean out does not fix the issue, a replacemnt board alone is about $200 then add whatever service fee the techs add and it could cost almost as much as a new laptop. At the time this laptop came out, it was about an $850 unit. correct? This would push it past $1000 in just parts.

If you go the way of the repair (motherboard as the graphics are mounted on the board) you should ask about warranty of the repair.

Comment: Thank you. Now they tell me that it is not the ati chip, it is the vga graphics chip. Any way, is it possible to replace that ?

Comment: I am not sure, but did you get a quote for the cost to fix?